# Android create JSONObject from string

Tags: android, json

I'm triyng to convert json in string format to a JSONObject.

My json (received from my server) is like

```
[{ "key": "value", "key2": "value2"}, { "key": "value2", "key2": "value3"}]
```

And i have tried

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
```

But obj is always null and my json is in a valid format (tested on http://jsonlint.com/)

Do I have to do smthing on my String first ?

Thanks,

Comment: if you look at this example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm you could still turn the string to a jsonObject, however you will need to surround the data with { }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to parse a `JSONArray` to `JSONOject`.

Do this

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(json);
```

**A thumb rule:** If JSON string starts with `[`, its an array and if it starts with `{` then its an object.

This is how you should parse it.

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(json);
for(int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject temp = obj.get(i);
    Log.d("Json parsing", "key: " + temp.optString("key"));
    Log.d("Json parsing", "key2: " + temp.optString("key2"));
}
```

Output will be

```
value
value2
value2
value3
```